# Concatenating element pairs of a list sequentially

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sliding-window

I am wondering what the pythonic way to accomplish the following would be. Suppose I have a list:

```
days = ['m', 't', 'w', 'r', 'f', 's', 's']
```

I would like to obtain a list which would look like:

```
['t-m', 'w-t', 'r-w', 'f-r', 's-f', 's-s']
```

so it would have to treat the original list as an iterator and move in order to perform the concatenation.

I would *think* this could be accomplished through some sort of list comprehension and use of the `iter()` function, but no luck in my attempts so far! I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) with a slice `days[1:]` and the original `days`, in a list comprehension, to iterate over a sliding window of reversed element pairs:

```
>>> days = ['m', 't', 'w', 'r', 'f', 's', 's']
>>> ['-'.join(pair) for pair in zip(days[1:], days)]
['t-m', 'w-t', 'r-w', 'f-r', 's-f', 's-s']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with enumerate, iterate over list exclude last item

```
>>> days = ['m', 't', 'w', 'r', 'f', 's', 's']
>>> ['{}-{}'.format(days[n+1], i) for n,i in enumerate(days[:-1])]
['t-m', 'w-t', 'r-w', 'f-r', 's-f', 's-s']
```